# How do I block syn floods? Preferably without running in Admin mode. Or do I not have to worry abut this?

Tags: tcp, syn, defense4all

zzzI am worried soeone is going to syn flood my TCP  server rendering it useless. I would like to find a way to protect against this.

I woud like to protect my TCP server from SYN floods. I have tried:

```
from rawsocketpy import RawRequestHandler, RawAsyncServerCallback
import time

def callback(handler, server):
    print("Testing")
    handler.setup()
    handler.handle()
    handler.finish()

class LongTaskTest(RawRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(self.packet)

    def finish(self):
        print("End")

    def setup(self):
        print("Begin") 

def main():
    rs = RawAsyncServerCallback("wlp2s0", 0xEEFA, LongTaskTest, callback)
    rs.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

But have not been able to test fpr syn floods.

Comment: A SYN flood can not be addressed within the application since the application gets only already accepted TCP connection.

Comment: You need specialized tools to stop a syn flood attack completely. However, you can create a mitigation plan for local machines. See how to analyze detect and mitigate syn flood attacks here: [syn flood attacks](https://www.powerwaf.com/learning/ddos-attacks/syn-flood-attack/)